# scrapyd only runs 2 jobs at the same time

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapyd

I was very happy with scrapy and scraped with max. 150 jobs at the same time.
I am using rotating proxies with no problems. I changed max proc a few times, and scraped along with 10 jobs because the server i scrape is not that strong.
After some time, scrapyd only runs 2 jobs at the same time.
I didn't changed anything in the scrapyd config or something.
This is my scrapyd config, stored in /etc/scrapyd/scrapyd.conf. Others conf files doesnt exists.

```
[scrapyd]
items_dir   = /root/scrapy/results/
max_proc    = 0
max_proc_per_cpu = 10
jobs_to_keep = 4000000
```

As said, i didnt changed it over time. I scraped with 10 jobs at the same time with this config.
Scrapyd daemonstatus says

```
{"status": "ok", "running": 2, "finished": 100, "pending": 7, "node_name": "..."}
```

I dont understand, why scrapyd stops doing what i should.
I did everything i can do to fix it.
 I runned scrapyd in other directorys, cleared the items and logs of the old jobs, but nothing changes. I double checked proxys and the spider code.

What could scrapyd stop running more jobs at the same time ? 
I'm really desperate :s

Comment: you have this problem in scrapinghub or in local?

Comment: @parik he is talking about `scrapyd`, so `scrapinghub` platform has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @v1nc maybe something to do with the amount of memory being used by those spiders, or even your cpu also being very busy (but I doubt it).

Comment: @eLRuLL yeah you're right, i didn't pay enough attention to title. thanks

Comment: @eLRuLL I double checked cpu usage, nothing unusual. I switched to scrapinghub now, but it makes me very sad anyway.